# React : Get data from Google Analytics API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I'm creating an application using **React** and **Laravel**.

I integrated successfuly **Google Analytics** using this [react-ga](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga) so when I check my Analytics dashboard the statistics of the pages of my project are there.

Now I want to display those data in my application to the users.

I've searched alot and I found that I need to use [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1). The problem here is that it request an authentification each time a user want to access to the data. Searched some more and **the solution was apparently to setup a [service account as a user in Google Analytics](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/).**

Now that I have the account set, the API key generated, I don't know how to call the data from the server to my application.

There is [this guide for javascript](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js) but I had a hard time implementing in React.